# Не работает оператор between с датами T-SQL

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Мне нужно вывести в datagridview все платежи с одной даты до другой (видно на скриншоте). В базе имеется один платеж с датой 30.05.2020 и он выводится в DGV только когда в обоих dateTimePicker стоит эта дата, во всех остальных случаях он остается пустым. Может кто-нибудь объяснить в чем проблема и помочь поправить запрос чтобы все работало?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поле BillDate в таблице имеет тип date.

```
    private void btnViewBills_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
DateTime fromDate = DateTime.Parse(dtpFromDate.Text);
DateTime toDate = DateTime.Parse(dtpToDate.Text);
con.Open();
dt = new DataTable();
adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from BillInfo where BillDate between '" + fromDate + "' and '" + toDate + "'", con);
adapt.Fill(dt);
billInfoDataGridView.DataSource = dt;
con.Close();
                }
```

Comment: Как правило, проблемы подобного рода возникают, когда формат подставляемой в текст запроса даты отличается от ожидаемого сервером ( обычно YYYY-MM-DD).

Comment: Зачем вы храните дату в строке? Почему не пользуетесь параметризированными запросами?

Comment: @Akina я изменил тип на date и немного изменил код, теперь формат на 100% совпадает (вывод значения поля BillDate из базы данных, переменные fromDate и toDate имеют такое же значение: https://prnt.sc/sqnsk7), но результат тот же.. Измененный код добавил в вопрос.

Comment: @АндрейNOP у меня была ошибка связанная с этим, я уже сам не помню какая(  Сейчас вот поставил опять, вроде норм, но запрос все равно не работает. А разве параметры можно добавлять к адаптеру? Или как это можно сделать?

Comment: *я изменил тип на date и немного изменил код, теперь формат на 100% совпадает (вывод значения поля BillDate из базы данных, переменные fromDate и toDate имеют такое же значение: prnt.sc/sqnsk7)* Вы способны отличить формат, в котором хранится значение, от формата, в котором его показывает (неизвестный нам) клиент? По-моему, нет... Какая разница, что происходит в вашей программе? главное - фигня на стороне SQL сервера. И пока даже неясно, присылаете Вы ему запрос на китайском, или интерпретируете не как нужно его ответ.

Comment: У SqlDataAdapter есть конструктор, принимающий команду. А команду можно сделать параметризированной

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
private void btnViewBills_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  DateTime fromDate = DateTime.Parse(dtpFromDate.Text);
  DateTime toDate = DateTime.Parse(dtpToDate.Text);
  con.Open();
  dt = new DataTable();
  String sqlExpression = "select * from BillInfo where BillDate between @fromDate and @toDate";
  SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlExpression);
  SqlParameter fromParam = new SqlParameter("@fromDate", fromDate);
  command.Parameters.Add(fromParam);
  SqlParameter toParam = new SqlParameter("@toDate", toDate);
  command.Parameters.Add(toParam);

  adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(command, con);
  adapt.Fill(dt);
  billInfoDataGridView.DataSource = dt;
  con.Close();
}
```